# Parsing INI file with PHP when amperstand (&) in value

Tags: php, ini

I want to parse an ini file. It has alphanumeric values as well as some special characters like (&#-@) etc. But it is not parsing correctly. I have recieved error message {E_WARNING: [/home/php/init/config.php:29] syntax error, unexpected '&' in .conf.ini on line 7}.
This is my ini file:

```
[Main]
DATABASE = test;
USER = root;
PASS = null;
HOST = localhost;
......
Def_Title = Welcome to Oggy & Chocroach.; //line 7
....
"Special & Featured" = "Alry Bee"; //line 17
```

I want to keep [&] operator in my fille. Any help may appreciated.

Comment: how are you trying to *parse* it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php):

> **Note**:
>   If a value in the ini file contains any non-alphanumeric characters it needs to be enclosed in double-quotes (`"`).

So the line should be:

```
Def_Title = "Welcome to Oggy & Chocroach."
```

You can't have `&` in the keys, only the values.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '"' in conf.ini on line 17

Comment: Only the value can contain `&`, not the parameter.